# Partial mocking in JMockit for each element in the Collection

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

I am using JMockit 1.10 and need to partially mock out a method for each element in a Collection.

I am able to do that if I pass them separately to new NonStrictExpectation like

```
final Object obj1 = objs.get(0);
final Object obj2 = objs.get(1);
new NonStrictExpectations(obj1, obj2) {{
    ...
}};
```

However it complains "Class is already mocked" if I pass them in a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    final Object _obj = objs.get(i);
    new NonStrictExpectations(_obj) {{
    }};
}
```

May I know why? Or what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information about what you're really trying to achieve, my guess is that the proper solution here is to partially mock the *class* of the elements in the collection, therefore mocking all such instances. Also, expectation blocks should never be created in a loop; there are other ways to deal with multiple invocations to the same mocked method.

Comment: Thanks @Rogério. Understood it can be done by the Static Partial Mocking or the Mockup api. However, as you said, both of them are not refactoring friendly. Is there a way to do it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, partially mock *the class*: `new NonStrictExpectations(ClassOfElementsInCollection.class) { ... }`.